# My PC doesn't have 2560x1080 resolution?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, display, resolution

I recently bought a new **LG widescreen monitor** (**2560 x 1080 px**, 34") but I **can't set an higher resolution** than 1920 x 1080 px. I tried to *update my drivers*, display adapters (Intel(R) HD Graphics) and monitor (it only says "generic pnp monitor"), still nothing happens.
I am using a vga to hdmi adapter.

I'm so ignorant about pc components but browsing the internet I found out that probably my problem is having an **integrated graphic card**. I was wondering if you can confirm my theory or point me to the right solution. 
If there isn't any other solutions could you suggest me a graphic card that can handle 2560x1080?

Sorry if I gave you less infos than necessary but I don't really know what you might need, I'm of course available for more details if I can provide them. Hope you'll excuse my poor grammar, I don't often speak english.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Hardware list:

[image]

Comment: What type of display connection (HDMI, DisplayPort, ...) are you using? Also please provide exact make and model for all hardware involved.

Comment: If you are unable to select the resolution it means your hardware (i.e. Intel iGPU) does not support it.

Comment: My PC has VGA but monitor has HDMI so I'm using a vga to hdmi adapter,

Comment: Please include the fact that you are using a VGA to HDMI adapter in your post. It most likely doesn't support resolutions higher than 1920x1080.

Comment: I added a list of hardware (I hope it's what you meant) and I mentioned the vga to hdmi adapter, thanks for the tips.

Comment: It would be a real mess if the problem is the adapter, unless there are other working solutions to connect vga pc to hdmi monitor

Comment: Make and specific model of PC please?

Comment: Which exact model of Intel HD Graphics do you have? Also which PC model?

Comment: That is Intel HD Graphics 2000. It maxes out at 2560x1600 so it should be able to run that monitor, but the VGA output is the limiting factor. There is also a DVI-D output on the computer DVI to HDMI converter/cable should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the VGA output on the computer.
A high-res monitor like that LG really has to be connected to a true digital output and your computer has one.
The big white connector next the the VGA output is DVI-D. That will be able to drive the monitor properly. (Should also fix the problem that the computer sees the monitor as a "generic VGA monitor", because that is also caused by the VGA to HDMI converter.
You will need a DVI to HDMI cable or DVI-HDMI converter in order to connect that to the HDMI input on your monitor.

Using the DVI-D will not only give you the full capability of the monitor, but will also give a better quality image.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Today arrived the new cable, [link] (https://www.amazon.it/AmazonBasics-adattatore-standard-recente-metri/dp/B014I8UQJY) , unfortunately I still have 1980 as max resolution